# Is there any function in dax for case statement like in sql

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, business-intelligence

I want to ask that do we have any statement in dax which works like Case statement in SQL
i.e.
in sql:

```
 case when pri column = 'p' then policy number end as policy pri  number
```

Comment: what did you find during your research?

Comment: actually i do it succesfully in sql but when fetch data using SQl statement my data model become very heavy and it took me immense time to gather data!

Comment: so i thought to do it in power bi!

Comment: Btw, case is an **expression**, not a statement.

Comment: i know right ! but any how i have found the solution and its working perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=dax+case) suggest the DAX [function SWITCH](https://dax.guide/switch/).

The way to use it you are looking for is with the `TRUE()` syntax as first argument. See below:

```
Something =
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    Some condition,
    Result,
    Some other condition,
    Other result,
    ...
    Result if no conditions are met
)
```

To further expand on this, based on the example SQL:

```sql
case when pri column = 'p' then policy number end as policy pri
```

Would be in DAX, as a new column

```
policy-pri =
SWITCH(
    table[pri],
    "p",
    table[policy number],
    BLANK()
)
```

In that case, the syntax using `TRUE()` is not needed. Even though, this example should work the same:

```
policy-pri =
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    table[pri] = "p",
    table[policy number],
    BLANK()
)
```

And, to elaborate even more. A *case* statement with just one case is just as good as an *if* statement:

```
policy-pri =
IF(
    table[pri] = "p",
    table[policy number],
    BLANK()
)
```

Comment: Kindly could you please elaborate it a little bit!

Comment: Pl ignore this comment. Sorry.